# Python 3.10 - ImportError for PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have built a program that edit excel sheets. I build a GUI with PyQt5 for it. I used Qt Creator to generate the code for the GUI. The program was working fine before, but after I tried to make it into an app with py2app and pyinstaller I keep getting an Import Error:

```
    (venv) Febins-MacBook-Pro:Planner Builder Febin.J$ "/Users/Febin.J/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/Planner Builder/venv/bin/python" "/Users/Febin.J/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/Planner Builder/birthdaywindow.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Febin.J/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/Planner Builder/birthdaywindow.py", line 11, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtCore' from 'PyQt5' (/Users/Febin.J/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/Planner Builder/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5/__init__.py)
```

The strange this is that it was working fine before. This is my packages installed:

```
altgraph==0.17.2
appscript==1.1.2
auto-py-to-exe==2.14.0
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
bottle==0.12.19
bottle-websocket==0.2.9
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.9
Eel==0.12.4
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
future==0.18.2
gevent==21.12.0
gevent-websocket==0.10.1
greenlet==1.1.2
idna==3.3
macholib==1.15.2
modulegraph==0.19.2
numpy==1.22.0
openpyxl==3.0.9
Pillow==8.4.0
psutil==5.9.0
py2app==0.26.1
pyinstaller==4.7
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2021.5
PyQt5==5.15.6
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.9.0
requests==2.26.0
soupsieve==2.3.1
urllib3==1.26.7
whichcraft==0.6.1
xlwings==0.25.3
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

This is where the error occurs:

```
1  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
2
3  # Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow.ui'
4  #
5  # Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
6  #
7  # WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
8  # run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.
9
10
11 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
12 import datetime
13 from datetime import *
14 from eventwindow import Ui_EventWindow
15 from webScraping import publicHolidays, schoolHolidays, uniHolidays
16 from main import creating_planner
```

Could you please help me solve this error?

Comment: Try upgrading pip

Answer (score 2):

I think there isn't support yet for `Python 3.10`:

https://github.com/altendky/pyqt-tools/issues/98

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. I'm pretty new to coding so I don't know much. I tried to change my Python Interpreter from 3.10 to 3.8 by clicking the bottom left corner on VS code. However, when I run the program on this interpreter all my packages are not imported. How can I keep my packages and run the program on Python 3.8?

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/ check this guide, it's better to use virtual environments as one package will not have impact on another Python version packages.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was finally able to install PyQt5 by forcing the version to 5.15.5 that is supported by Python 3.10. You can use the below command line:

```
pip install PyQt5==5.15.5
```

Comment: Not worked for me

Comment: What is your version of python?